# Blazor JSRuntime Focus on Element in foreach

Tags: blazor

When I create a new form in my 'formset', I want to focus the new form.

With this code I got the desired result, but i get a 'An unhandled error has occurred. Reload' and the following errors in the console:

[errors in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3IUD.png)

Many thanks!

```
<EditForm Model="todos" OnValidSubmit="Save">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>TODO</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var todo in todos)
            {
                if (todos.IndexOf(todo) != todos.Count - 1)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input @bind="@todo.Name" /></td>
                    </tr>
                }
                if (todos.IndexOf(todo) == todos.Count - 1)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input @ref="element" @onkeydown="@((KeyboardEventArgs e) => Newline(e))" @bind="@todo.Name" /></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
</EditForm>
```

In my code block:

```
ElementReference element;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
     await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setFocusOnElement", element);
}
```

site.js:

```
function setFocusOnElement(element) {
    element.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spite of the error message, I believe this is related to the timing of the rendering... Call InvokeVoidAsync like this:

```
ElementReference element;

 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
 {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("exampleJsFunctions.focusElement", element);
         }
     }
```

_Host.cshtml:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
<script>

    window.exampleJsFunctions =
    {
        focusElement: function (element) {
           element.focus();
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: if(**!firstRender**) did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Can you update your answer so i can accept?